# Is there a 301 Redirect directive that will catch-all of a URL parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I believe my question is rather unique. I looked around and couldn't find an answer.

There are several reports in Webmaster Tools showing URLs if this nature:

```
website.com/shop/?orderby=date
```

Is there an .htaccess line(s) of code that will redirect the above URL to

```
website.com/shop/
```

and that the redirect would be a 301?

Thank you

Comment: Based on your tags I would assume you're using Apache HTTPD.  Is that correct?

Comment: I can see nothing much “unique” about this question. // If you want to check query string contents, then you have to use a `RewriteCond` to do so.

Comment: _“and if it's on any sub-page, it will redirect to the main sub page it was used it the URL”_ – and that bit needs clarification. What do you consider a “sub page”, and what would be the “main sub page” to that? The least you can do, is show a few from->to example URLs.

Answer (score 1):

That seems relatively straight forward. If you're just wanting to search out "orderby=val" in the query string and if found, redirect to the base URI, try this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} orderby=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=301]
```

This assumes you've enabled the rewrite module in the main config:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

**UPDATED:** Example 2:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} orderby=
RewriteRule ^shop/ products? [R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, this is actually turning out to be more complex than I thought. Is there an edit of your code where I can just do one at a time? For instance we have many URLs found (which don't exist) of the following: /shop/?orderby=date --- can you show my one piece of code that would address only that URL and redirect it to "any page" I like? In this case it would be redirected (301) to website.com/products/ --- thanks Brandon!

Comment: Yes, you can modify the RewriteRule's pattern to be more discriminating so it only acts on specific URI matches... e.g. /shop/ and modify the substitution to redirect to whatever URI you want. I've updated my answer with a second example for this. Helpful documentation: [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters)

Comment: @njames Was the second example helpful?

Comment: Hey Brandon thanks for your answers. It seems none of your solutions worked though. I'll bet it's a sever setting although the site is using wordpress, and there's a mod_rewrite module that seems to be used/working. Either way, your first solution caused a 500 error on pages with orderby=anything, and the second solution didn't do anything - the orderby=anything remained in the URL. I'm going to try another revision of my question. Again thank you.

Comment: @njames Sorry to hear those didn't work. There's definitely something else in play here then. Neither of those RewriteRules (by themselves) would carry over the querystring (orderby=). So there would have to be an execution scope issue or some other Rewrite or Redirect or Alias...etc. that is conflicting (i.e. pre or post processing the result).

Comment: You might be right and probably are - we've got woocommerce installed and I'll bet it's conflicting the rewrite rules and so forth. I'll have to look in another direction. I'll update this post if I find something. Thanks Brandon.